# Change background-color , below gallery images in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, css

you can see gallery images
below gallery images, you can see pink color background, which has text "white boards"
please help me to change the background-color from pink to black.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about css not magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tp-simpleresponsive .caption.bkg_color, .tp-simpleresponsive .tp-caption.bkg_color{
   color: #000;
}
```

Instead of asking these kind of question , try to inspect the element. Follow this steps

http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Inspect-Element-in-Mozilla-Firefox

and get this plugin for webdesign http://getfirebug.com/css

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am new to this programming world. I will try to use inspect element.

Comment: @user3483987 All the best.. Enjoy the coding :)